# Ballerina API to concatenate all items in a list

Tags: ballerina

Is there a Ballerina API to concatenate all items in a list?
For example,

```php
string[] users = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
```

I need to concatenate all the users in the above list to `user1user2user3` I can do it by looping through the array  and concatenating. But is there any packages or apis available in ballerina to make that easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is more scalable approach to achieve the same, using `array` lang-lib functions.

```php
 string[] users = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];
 string str = users.reduce(function(string result, string val) returns string => result + val, "");
```

Unlike `string:concat` function, this approach can be extended to concatenate non-string arrays as well.

E.g: Concatenating integer array into a single string

```php
int[] users = [1, 2, 3];
string str = users.reduce(function(string result, int val) returns string => result + val.toBalString(), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use, `string:concat` with the array in a rest argument.

```php
string[] users = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];
string str = string:concat(...users);
```